# Vuex - action dispatched in created() doesn't run until window reload?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, action, dispatch

In my App.vue I (want to) dispatch two actions to do API calls and set data, but they will not 'dispatch' until page refresh.

The below two actions get dispatched in the `created()` life cycle of App.js right after login and I do a router push to the webroot `/`. I replaced the router push after login with a hard `window.location.href = "/"` and that makes them dispatch, but I want to understand why it's not happening on a router push.

I've tried putting the dispatch lines in `mounted()` as well, but no luck.

```
created: function () {
  state.commit("initialiseStore");
  this.$store.dispatch("loadLocations");
  this.$store.dispatch("loadCategories");
},
```

Comment: did you try `beforeRouteEnter` hook  or `beforeEnter` guard?

Comment: Not related to your issue but why do you use `state.commit` instead of `this.$store.commit`?